# After editing data, redux cannot read id

Tags: reactjs, redux

i have a problem.
I use a form to edit my data, then when i want to see edited data, i get an ×

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
```

Pointing at my

```
 {users &&
        users.map((user) => {
          return (
            <div key={user.id}>
              <Link to={`users/${user.id}`}> {user.name} </Link>
            </div>
          );
        })}
```

Which is used to display data.
After refreshing the site (F5) it works, so i assume that the redux has problem with reading edited data for the first time, altough it do work with adding new data. anyone know what i can do?
My `UserEditForm`:

```
const UserEditForm = () => {
  let { id } = useParams();
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    name: "",
    birthday: "",
    img: "",
  });
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  console.log(id);

  let history = useHistory();
  let dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { name, birthday, img } = state;
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getSingleUser(id));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      setState({ ...user });
    }
  }, [user]);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    let { name, value } = e.target;
    setState({ ...state, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    dispatch(updateUser(state, id));
    history.push("/");
    setError("");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        style={{ width: "100px", marginTop: "20px" }}
        variant="contained"
        color="secondary"
        onClick={() => history.push("/")}
      >
        Go Back
      </Button>
      <h2>Edit User</h2>
      {error && <h3 style={{ color: "red" }}>{error}</h3>}
      <form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <TextField
          id="standard-basic"
          label="Name"
          value={name || ""}
          name="name"
          type="text"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <br />
        <TextField
          id="standard-basic"
          label="birthday"
          name="birthday"
          value={birthday || ""}
          type="birthday"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <br />
        <TextField
          id="standard-basic"
          label="img"
          value={img || ""}
          name="img"
          type="number"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />

        <Button
          style={{ width: "100px" }}
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          type="submit"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        >
          Update
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
export default UserEditForm;
```

My `UserList` component:

```
const UserList = ({ users, history }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const fetchUsers = async () => {
    const response = await axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/characters")
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Err: ", err);
      });
    dispatch(setUsers(response.data));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
  }, []);
  console.log(users);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => history.goBack()}>...back</button>
      <li>
        <Link to="/user/add">Add Users</Link>
      </li>
      {users &&
        users.map((user) => {
          return (
            <div key={user.id}>
              <Link to={`users/${user.id}`}> {user.name} </Link>
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    users: state.allUsers.users,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(UserList);
```

Comment: will adding loading help?

Comment: You problem in `redux` when you update user in array of users , can you share `updateUser` action with reducer ?

Comment: @VitaliyRayets reducer: https://pastebin.com/m20euG0b  updateUser action: https://pastebin.com/bpRdbizp

Comment: You miss throw data response to function argument . See correct code `dispatch(userUpdated(resp));`.

Comment: @VitaliyRayets thanks, it did work. Although for some reason, the React gives a warning:  Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. But as you can see in my UserList component,  i provide a key={user.id}. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Maybe some ids of users is not unique. Try `users.map((user, index) => {return(<div key={index}>`